# Наглухо зависает Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, scripts

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема, что после нажатия кнопки play, при попытке сделать свайп, unity намертво глохнет и приходится через диспетчер задач её выключать.У меня есть 3 подозреваемых: GameController, скрипт отвечающий за сферу или SwipeController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speedOfMovement = 20;
    public float speedOfSpawn = 5f;
    public GameObject whatToMove;
    private Transform posOfRocket;
    public Transform spawnZone;
    private Collider MetColl;
    public GameObject objToSpawn;
    float maxZ;
    float nowX = 0f;
    string Direction;
    Sphere sphere;
    void Start() {
            posOfRocket = whatToMove.GetComponent<Transform>(); //получение компонента ракеты
            MetColl = objToSpawn.GetComponent<BoxCollider>(); // получение коллизии метеорита
            StartCoroutine(SpawnMeteorite());
            sphere = objToSpawn.GetComponent<Sphere>();
            Direction = sphere.WhatToDisable;
            SwipeController.SwipeEvent += CheckInput;
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnMeteorite() {
            while(true) {
                SpawnMet();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(speedOfSpawn);
            }
    }
    private void SpawnMet() {
            maxZ = spawnZone.position.z;  // спавн метеорита
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(nowX , spawnZone.position.y, maxZ);
            Instantiate(objToSpawn, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    void Update() {
            posOfRocket.Translate(0, speedOfMovement * Time.deltaTime, 0); // движение ракеты
    }
    public void CheckInput(SwipeController.SwipeType type)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitForSwipe(type));
    }
    IEnumerator WaitForSwipe(SwipeController.SwipeType dirOfSwipe)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Direction == "up" && dirOfSwipe == SwipeController.SwipeType.UP)
            {
                Debug.Log("up");
            }
            else if (Direction == "down" && dirOfSwipe == SwipeController.SwipeType.DOWN)
            {
                Debug.Log("down");
            }
            else if (Direction == "right" && dirOfSwipe == SwipeController.SwipeType.RIGHT)
            {
                Debug.Log("right");
            }
            else if (Direction == "left" && dirOfSwipe == SwipeController.SwipeType.LEFT)
            {
                Debug.Log("left");
            }
        }
    }
    


}
```

Sphere:

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Sphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject LeftText;
    public GameObject RightText;
    public GameObject UpText;
    public GameObject DownText;
    private string[] direction = {"up", "left", "right", "down"};
    private System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    public string WhatToDisable;
    GameObject gameControler;
    GameController callingMethod;
    private void Start()
    {
        callingMethod = gameControler.GetComponent<GameController>();
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
        string dir = direction[rnd.Next(0, 3)];
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            switch (dir) {
                case "up":
                    UpText.SetActive(true);
                    WhatToDisable = "up";
                    break;
                case "left":
                    LeftText.SetActive(true);
                    WhatToDisable = "left";
                    break;
                case "right":
                    RightText.SetActive(true);
                    WhatToDisable = "right";
                    break;
                case "down":
                    DownText.SetActive(true);
                    WhatToDisable = "down";
                    break;
            }}
            Time.timeScale = 0.1f;
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("some text");
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            switch(WhatToDisable) {
                case "up":
                    UpText.SetActive(false);
                    break;
                case "left":
                    LeftText.SetActive(false);
                    break;
                case "right":
                    RightText.SetActive(false);
                    break;
                case "down":
                    DownText.SetActive(false);
                    break;
            }

            Time.timeScale = 1;
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 1;
        }

    }
}
```

и
SwipeController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool IsDragging, isMobilePlatform;
    Vector2 tapPoint, swipeDelta;
    float minSwipeDelta = 130;
    public enum SwipeType
    {
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        UP,
        DOWN
    }
    public delegate void OnSwipeInput(SwipeType type);
    public static event OnSwipeInput SwipeEvent;
    private void Awake() 
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDLONE
            isMobilePlatform = false;
        #else
            isMobilePlatform = true;
        #endif
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isMobilePlatform)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                IsDragging = true;
                tapPoint = Input.mousePosition;
            }
            else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                ResetSwipe();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    IsDragging = true;
                    tapPoint = Input.touches[0].position;
                }
                else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    ResetSwipe();
                }
            }
        }
        CalculateSwipe();
    }
    void CalculateSwipe()
    {
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (IsDragging)
        {
            if (!isMobilePlatform && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - tapPoint;
            }
            else if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - tapPoint;
            }
        }
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > minSwipeDelta)
        {
            if (SwipeEvent != null)
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDelta.x) > Mathf.Abs(swipeDelta.y))
                {
                    SwipeEvent(swipeDelta.x < 0 ? SwipeType.LEFT : SwipeType.RIGHT);
                }
                else
                {
                    SwipeEvent(swipeDelta.y > 0 ? SwipeType.UP : SwipeType.DOWN);
                }

            }
            ResetSwipe();
        }
    }
    void ResetSwipe()
    {
        IsDragging = false;
        tapPoint = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
    
}
```

Может кто нибудь подсказать, в чём проблема.

Comment: `WaitForSwipe`  без конечный  цикл `while`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В скрипте GameController в самом низу у вас в IEnumerator WaitForSwipe() идет бесконечный цикл while(true), который выводит просто строки в консоль. Из-за этого бесконечного цикла Unity и замирает наглухо.

P.S. Если в этой функции вы просто выводите строки в консоль, то скорее всего делаете это для проверки правильности работы скрипта? Если да, то лучше делать что-то подобное в функции Update, чтобы проверять каждый кадр. Ну или оставить эту функцию, но между итерациями цикла добавить

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(int i);
```

Чтобы программа не висла, а просто выполняла итерацию цикла, ждала i секунд, итерация цикла, ожидание и т.д.

P.P.S. А вообще бесконечные циклы это плохая штука. С ними надо очень аккуратно.